# Подскажите почему не срабатывает e.preventDefault()

Tags: jquery

> https://codepen.io/vladlerOK/pen/JwZxOZ

```js
var scriptURL = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz_YY59bLifVrQo66V3r5Me4_uU8qByuwmo1CUr0KlSdAITx5Q/exec';

submit.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  // formObj.find('.form-group').slideUp();
  $("form").find('.loader').fadeIn();

  var formData = new FormData(document.forms.formw);

  var phoneWa = $("#secondSelect").val() + $('input[name="phone"]').val();
  formData.set('phone', phoneWa);


  fetch(scriptURL, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(function(e) {
      window.location.href = "/thanks.html";
    }, 200)
  }).catch(function(error) {
    formObj.find('.loader').fadeOut();
    console.error('Error!', error.message);
  });
};
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не срабатывает? Есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера?

Comment: Редирект происходит после нажатия на форму, выше в коде прописаны ошибки если не заполнены поля, а когда я их не заполняю редирект происходит

Comment: добавь пример разметки, с твоим элементом `submit`

Comment: В идеале дополнить код в вопросе до [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить тут и посмотреть поведение.

Comment: я кинул полный код в https://codepen.io/vladlerOK/pen/JwZxOZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде все плохо: на одну кнопку добавлен и обработчик jQuery, и нативный обработчик через присваивание `onclick`.

`Submit` **вне** формы не вызывает отправку формы, если не установлен атрибут [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form).

В данном случае атрибут не установлен, поэтому отправка формы не будет выполнена в любом случае, и можно убрать вызов `e.preventDefault()` как ненужный.

#### Что происходит на самом деле?

Проверки выполняются в обработчике добавленном `jQuery`, что никак не влияет на обработчик добавленный через `.onclick =` .

Из-за отсутствия проверок в последнем обработчике идет простой вызов `fetch` и редирект.

---

Лобовым решением может стать вызов `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` в случае когда запрос не должен быть послан в обработчике добавленном в jquery.

---

Лучшим решением было бы переписать полностью разметку и все обработчики в едином стиле.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать, отпишу если все получится